# Create MySQL Table Using Dynamically Created Form

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to create a form that allows users to create a MySQL table using a dynamically generated from. The user initially inputs the desired table name, and then the number of rows they want. When they type the number, an equal amount of form rows are created. Each field created has a name like "fieldName[]". My hope was to create an array, and then use the created array to complete the table creation query. I could get it to work how I wanted if I used something like:

```
$myarray = array("key1"=>array($fieldName[0],$fieldName[1],$fieldName[2]),
    "key2"=>array($fieldType[0],$fieldType[1],$fieldType[2]),
     "key3"=>array($fieldLength[0],$fieldLength[1],$fieldLength[2]));
```

Javascript Dynamic Row Creator:

```
function numFields(nums) {
var str = "";
for (i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
    str += '<p><label style="padding-left:10px;">Name: <input type="text" value="fred'+(i+1)+'" name="Name[]" id="newtblname'+(i+1)+'" /></label></p>';
}
document.getElementById('Fields').innerHTML = str;
}
```

And the PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['tabletest'])) {
$Name=$_POST['Name'];
$x=0;
foreach($Name as $value) {
    $names= $value;
    echo $Name[$x];
    echo "<br>";
    $x++;
}
}
```

Solution: Here is the code I got to work:

```
$fieldsNum = $_POST['fieldsNum'];
$tblName = $_POST['tblName'];
$nameArray=$_POST['Name'];
$x = 0;

$tables = 'CREATE TABLE '.$tblName.' (';
foreach($nameArray as $value) {
$tables .= $value . " CHAR(200)"; 
$x++;
if($x<$fieldsNum) {
$tables .= ", ";
}

}
$tables .= ');';

echo $tables;
}
```

Comment: Dear the thing you are describing can be done. but you have to update your question and show what have you tried. people will not code for you here. they will see your code if some thing missing they will give you suggesstion. Thanks.

Comment: Is this on the public internet? If so, how are you going to secure it?

Comment: I have updated my question to include things I have tried. As for if it is on the public internet. No. This is for my coworkers and me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a form in your HTML like:

```
<form method="post" action="tableCreate.php">
<input type="text" name="fieldName[]"><br>
.
.
.
<button type="submit">Go!</button>
</form>
```

Then in tableCreate.php you should see them as

```
$tableArray = $_POST['fieldName'];
$tables = 'CREATE TABLE tblName (';    

foreach($tableArray as $value) {
$tables .= $value . " CHAR(200), ";
}
$tables .= ');';

echo $tables;
```

This would loop through the array and put each table name in the string which you could later use for creating the tables.

(I can not test this at the moment, but it should be fine).

Comment: This works, except that at the end, there is a comma that prevents the query from working. I need to find a way to get rid of the comma.

Comment: Worked with it a bit, and I got it to work. I don't know how to/if I can post code as a comment, so refer to my updated question for how I changed it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ChrisBuckley Sorry - didn't see that message that you need help with it. As I understand you are alright now? Glad that I could help you in some way :)